# Python merge equivalent to SQL join with like operator

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, merge, sql-like

I have one Pandas DataFrame1 that contains names.

```
column1:    column2:
John        some_value
Steve       some_value
Mark        some_value
```

Another DataFrame2 that contains full names.

```
column1:        column2:
John Smith      some_value
Steve James     some_value
Mark Taylor     some_value
```

I need to make a marge equivalent to SQL:

```
select
     df1.column1
    ,df2.column2
from DataFrame1 df1
join DataFrame2 df2
  on df1.column1 like '%' + df2.column1 + '%'
```

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
inputdataframe1 = [['John', 4],['Steve', 5],['Mark', 6]]
inputdataframe2= [['John smith', 9],['Steve James', 8],['Mark Taylor', 4]]
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(inputdataframe1)
dataframe2= pd.DataFrame(inputdataframe2)
merged_dataframe = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_on=[0],right_on=[0],how='outer')
```

output will be  like this as we cannot merge it directly

```
        0   1_x     1_y
0   John    4.0     NaN
1   Steve   5.0     NaN
2   Mark    6.0     NaN
3   John smith  NaN 9.0
4   Steve James NaN 8.0
5   Mark Taylor NaN 4.0
```

if you are in need join two dataframe using **like** below code will help you

```
import pandas as pd
inputdataframe1 = [['John', 4],['Steve', 5],['Mark', 6]]
inputdataframe2= [['John smith', 9],['Steve James', 8],['Mark Taylor', 4]]
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(inputdataframe1)
dataframe2= pd.DataFrame(inputdataframe2)
dataframe1_names=[key for key,value in inputdataframe1]
dataframe2_names=[key for key,value in inputdataframe2]
d=dict(inputdataframe1)
list_like_values=[[dataframe2_names[j],d[dataframe1_names[i]]] for i in range(len(dataframe2_names)) for j  in range(len(dataframe1_names)) if(dataframe1_names[i] in dataframe2_names[j])]
dataframe1= pd.DataFrame(list_like_values)
merged_dataframe = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_on=[0],right_on=[0],how='inner')
```

output will be in the form as below

```
    0   1_x     1_y
0   John smith  4   9
1   Steve James 5   8
2   Mark Taylor 6   4
```